# How do I predict using a trained Image to Emotion Pytorch model

Tags: python, pytorch

We have found [Artemis](https://github.com/optas/artemis), a good project that predicts emotions based on art images.
The model is available for download as a `.pt` file.

How can I use the model? I want to check them with some images to see if they're good.

I am loading the model with:

```
DEFAULT_MODEL_PATH = 'models/artemis/best_model.pt'

model = torch_load_model(DEFAULT_MODEL_PATH, 'cpu')
# c=model.eval()
# print(c)
 
image = Image.open("sample_images/neoclassicism_romantics_art_nouveau.jpg")

# this section to transform I don't know what it does 

trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.Resize(32),
    transforms.CenterCrop(32),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])
input = trans(image)

input = input.view(1, 3, 32, 32)
output = model(input)
print(output)
prediction = int(torch.max(output.data, 1)[1].numpy())
print(prediction)
```

The above transform code I found on other SO answer, but being a newbie to ML I don't know what they do.

This code returns sometimes:

```
tensor([[-2.6041, -1.6840, -1.5014, -2.5007, -3.4555, -2.7803, -2.8510, -1.9448,
         -1.9579]], grad_fn=<LogSoftmaxBackward0>)
2
```

sometimes this:

```
tensor([[-2.8087, -1.4727, -1.5604, -2.5557, -3.7794, -2.9126, -2.6383, -1.8776,
         -2.1111]], grad_fn=<LogSoftmaxBackward0>)
1
```

Which I don't know what they are.
What I miss to run a prediction? I would love to see the labels and the predicted values.

Answer (score 0):

`output` is the output of the neural network, which represents the probability of pre-defined classes. It seems that the total class number is 9 since the size of the `output` is 9.

Therefore, `prediction` is the index of the most likable class.

And also, the network's prediction could change due to the randomness of input transforms and itself. I recommend modifying your code like this:

```
DEFAULT_MODEL_PATH = 'models/artemis/best_model.pt'

model = torch_load_model(DEFAULT_MODEL_PATH, 'cpu')
model.eval()
# print(c)
 
image = Image.open("sample_images/neoclassicism_romantics_art_nouveau.jpg")

# this section to transform I don't know what it does 

trans = transforms.Compose([
#    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.Resize(32),
#    transforms.CenterCrop(32),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])
input = trans(image)

input = input.view(1, 3, 32, 32)
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input)
    prediction = int(torch.max(output.data, 1)[1].numpy())
print(output)
print(prediction)
```

- `model.eval()` changes some operations (batchnorm, dropout, etc) in the network for inference
- Discard `transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip()` for removing randomness
- Discard `transforms.CenterCrop(32)` since it seems to do nothing since the image has resized to size of 32
- `with torch.no_grad()` tells torch not to compute gradient

Any advise is welcomed